# not able to redirect to different language based on country in wordpress using polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang, language-switching

Hi I am using polylang multilingual plugin with woocommerce for my wordpress site. The plugin is working fine overall but recently client needed a new feature as 'Detect the users location based on ip and redirect them as: sweden - swedish, norway - norwegian, denmark - danish, others - english'. For the new requirement I added plugin 'polylang - country detection' and then deactivated the settings of 'detect browser language' in polylang settings.

Issue is it's still not working as per the requirement. Every time it's showing swedish language site( i.e. default language of polylang ). Do I need to add filter or something like that for the polylang country detection to work ? Currently my wordpress version is 6.2, polylang version 3.3.3 & polylang country detection version is 1.3.1.

Am I missing something ?
Any help/suggestions are welcome.